# Drupal 7, taxonomy exposed filter

Tags: drupal-taxonomy

I am working with drupal 7. How do I limit a taxonomy dropdown exposed filter to only display the terms used by nodes in view results?

I understand that the list is populated before the views takes place, but this means that i am often left with tags that display nothing ( since they are hidden with my view) any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In views:

**Filter Criteria**

Add - Content: Has taxonomy terms

**Settings:** Select the Vocabulary name.

Checkbox **Expose this filter to visitors.**

If you are using single filter select that, where you can see the list of Taxonomy terms. If you have child terms select `hierarchy` check box and specify the depth of it. only appears when you **Add - Content: Has taxonomy terms (with Depth)** -- refer to second step above.

Now select the terms you want to display, and make sure to checkbox **Limit list to selected items**

You can also add (**Global: text area**) under **No result behavior** in **Advanced** if you still want to show all taxonomy terms but want to show some thing to user like `coming soon` instead of leaving the selected taxonomy term showing empty page.